# Use Small Caps of ttf font with xetex in plain tex (without fontspec)

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex, small-caps

I want to use the small caps of the font CormorantGaramond-Light.ttf. With XeLaTeX I could just do

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cormorant Garamond Light}

\begin{document}
\scshape Hello World
\end{document}
```

How can I do the same in plain TeX without using fontspec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\fontname\font` in the LaTeX document to see what font is used by `fontspec`. For example:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CormorantGaramond-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}
\scshape \fontname\font, Hello World
\end{document}
```

You can see in this example:

```
"[CormorantGaramond-Regular.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text"
```

So, your plain TeX document can look like:

```
\font\f="[CormorantGaramond-Regular.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text"

\f Hello world

\bye
```

Note that the font feature `+smcp` does this folk: it switches the font to the Caps and Small caps mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the font-filename that houses the sc version you want.   I don't have your exact font, but I show the technique, here for XeTeX.

```
\font \ariblk="[ariblk.ttf]" at 11pt
\font \corsclight="[CormorantSC-Light.ttf]" at 11pt

Default
\ariblk  Arial Black
\corsclight And now CormorantSC-Light
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is no sc version of the font. So how is latex able to set small caps?

Comment: I think you are using another font: your example calls `Cormorant Garamond Light`, while Steven's calls `CormorantSC-Light`.

Comment: @jarnosz I believe you are right that our fonts are different.  However, the technique should apply. Wipet's answer is better, because he specifies an option from the base-font for automatically accessing the sc version.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes indeed.